# How to automatically force full composition pipeline for Nvidia GPU driver?

Tags: nvidia, manjaro, gpu, proprietary-drivers

I've installed Manjaro Linux. My graphics card is an Nvidia GTX 1050Ti.

When I boot my computer and try to watch videos, I notice harsh screen tearing. This problem is resolved when I go to the Nvidia X Server Settings and enable the option "Force Full Composition Pipeline".

Is there any way to permanently set this option so that I don't have to manually enable it every time I reboot my computer?

Answer (score 15):

My laptop is equipped with a Quadro K2100M, running Ubuntu Bionic with KDE Plasma 5.17 (from the [neon repo](https://neon.kde.org)) and using the `nvidia-driver-430`.

Since I have a different set of configurations for the monitors at home and at work, I needed something dynamic and here is what is working for me:

1. I wrote the following script to handle the dynamic configuration of the screens (`~/bin/force-composition-pipeline.sh`):

   ```bsh
   #!/bin/bash
   s="$(nvidia-settings -q CurrentMetaMode -t)"

   if [[ "${s}" != "" ]]; then
     s="${s#*" :: "}"
     nvidia-settings -a CurrentMetaMode="${s//\}/, ForceCompositionPipeline=On\}}"
   fi
   ```
2. I added that script to the autostart:

   ```bsh
   chmod +x ~/bin/force-composition-pipeline.sh
   ln -s ~/bin/force-composition-pipeline.sh ~/.config/autostart-scripts/
   ```
3. In KDE Plasma settings, in **Display and Monitor** -> **Compositor**, I set the **Tearing prevention ("vsync")** to *Never*.

Note that I found the non-full `ForceCompositionPipeline` to be enough for me.

Comment: Thank you so much! I have been looking for this automatic solution for about more than 1 year....

Comment: It works. `ForceFullCompositionPipeline` works better for me instead of `ForceCompositionPipeline`

Answer (score 3):

Adding to Paradox's answer (since it seems I can't post comments...), I would put that command in ~/.bash_profile rather than in ~/.bashrc.

~/.bashrc is sourced every time you open a new bash session, i.e. every time you open a new terminal emulator window/tab.

On the other hand ~/.bash_profile is sourced only once when you start bash as a login shell, e.g. when you log in a graphical desktop environment. c.f. https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html#Bash-Startup-Files

EDIT: There's now a better solution to the tearing issue with KWin when using the nvidia proprietary driver; you need to have a recent enough version of kwin, version >= 5.12 [1] *and* enable modesetting for the nvidia-drm kernel module [2]. I tested that and it works for me with kwin-5.17.80 (git snapshot from openSuse repos) and nvidia 440.26.

EDIT: hmm, there's a side effect to enabling modeset with the nvidia-drm module, resuming from suspend seems to fail...

EDIT (again): it looks like even without enabling modeset with the nvidia-drm module, tearting seems to be gone, for now at least...

[1]https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/NVIDIA/Troubleshooting#Avoid_screen_tearing_in_KDE_(KWin)
   https://phabricator.kde.org/D19867

[2]https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/NVIDIA#DRM_kernel_mode_setting

Answer (score 2):

You can set the "*Force Full Composition Pipeline*" option in a terminal, like this:

```
$ nvidia-settings --assign CurrentMetaMode="nvidia-auto-select +0+0 { ForceFullCompositionPipeline = On }"
```

To do it automatically, the easiest way to do so is to put it inside your `.bashrc`. To proceed just type this inside a terminal:

```
$ echo "$ nvidia-settings --assign CurrentMetaMode=\"nvidia-auto-select +0+0 { ForceFullCompositionPipeline = On }\"" >> ~/.bashrc
```

You can log out and log back in (or reboot), to have this applied. Note that this is meant to be a one monitor solution only, because of the "auto-select".

Another method would be to do the same inside `~/.nvidia-settings-rc` but the behaviour could change over time, while in `.bashrc`, you are sure on how it is done.

### Addendum

Regarding screen tearing, you might want to try other tweaks.

Since you are using Manjaro, I assume you are using KDE. You can tell the window manager (KWin) to use triple buffering or to wait for the current image to be displayed before updating the screen.

#### 1) Wait for the GPU to fully display current image

```
# echo "export __GL_YIELD=\"USLEEP\"" >> /etc/profile.d/kwin.sh
```

#### 2) Enable triple buffering in KWin

```
# echo "export KWIN_TRIPLE_BUFFER=1" >> /etc/profile.d/kwin.sh
```

*Do not have both of the above enabled at the same time*. Be sure to enable triple buffering in `nvidia-settings` if you enable triple buffering in KWin.

Comment: If he has a xorg.conf file it can be added there to make it perm which would be the correct method.

Answer (score 2):

**For Single Monitor:**

Create a text file and paste this:

```
[Desktop Entry]
Type=Application
Name=nvidia-force-full-compositon
Exec=nvidia-settings --assign CurrentMetaMode="nvidia-auto-select +0+0 { ForceFullCompositionPipeline = On }"
```

**For Dual Monitor:**

if you have a dual monitor you can open this file in text editor: `/etc/X11/xorg.conf`
Then do a search with this word `metamodes`with ctrl+F and see what it has configured. mine is something like this:

```
"metamodes" "DVI-I-0: nvidia-auto-select +1920+0 {ForceCompositionPipeline=On}, HDMI-0: nvidia-auto-select +0+0
```

so I have created the destop entry like this:

```
[Desktop Entry]
Type=Application
Name=nvidia-force-full-compositon
Exec=nvidia-settings --assign CurrentMetaMode="nvidia-auto-select +1920+0 {ForceCompositionPipeline=On}, nvidia-auto-select +0+0 { ForceCompositionPipeline = On }"
```

**NOTE: You can either do ForceFullCompositionPipeline or ForceCompositionPipeline only. Just change the text as you need.**

save the text file as something like this:

```
nvidia-force-full-compositon.desktop
```

where `.desktop` is essential.

Now copy paste it in `~/.config/autostart`

Reboot.

Answer (score 2):

you can create a file called /etc/X11/xorg.conf.d/20-nvidia.conf

And add these lines

```
Section "Device"
        Identifier "Nvidia Card"
        Driver     "nvidia"
        VendorName "NVIDIA Corporation"
        BoardName  "GeForce GTX 1050 Ti"
EndSection

Section "Screen"
    Identifier     "Screen0"
    Device         "Device0"
    Monitor        "Monitor0"
    Option         "metamodes" "nvidia-auto-select +0+0 {ForceFullCompositionPipeline=On}"
    Option         "AllowIndirectGLXProtocol" "off"
    Option         "TripleBuffer" "on"
EndSection
```

more info: https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/NVIDIA/Troubleshooting#Bad_performance_after_installing_a_new_driver_version

Answer (score 0):

Since I sometimes use a dual monitor setup and sometimes a quadruple monitor setup I wanted to have the script a bit more dynamic. Therefore I wrote this script which first retrieves the `CurrentMetaMode`, analyses it and adds the necessary options if needed to all connected and active monitors.

```bash
#!/bin/bash

# Avoids getting this error: Gtk-Message: 21:17:19.921: Failed to load module "xapp-gtk3-module"
extraOpts=("--use-gtk2")

# Set to false if you don't want/need the full composition pipeline
full_composition_pipeline=true

current_meta_mode="$(nvidia-settings "${extraOpts[@]}" --query CurrentMetaMode --terse)"
meta_mode_splitted="${current_meta_mode#*" :: "}"
meta_mode_converted="$(sed -E 's/\b([^: ]+):\s*([^{]+?)\s*\{([^}]+)\}(,\s*|$)/\1:\2:\3:\4\n/g' <<< "$meta_mode_splitted")"

changed=false
new_meta_mode=""
while IFS=":" read -r display resolution options end; do
    if ! [[ "$options" == *"ForceCompositionPipeline=On"* ]]; then
        options="$options, ForceCompositionPipeline=On"
        changed=true
        echo "${display}: Add ForceCompositionPipeline=On"
    fi
    if ! [[ "$options" == *"ForceFullCompositionPipeline=On"* ]] && ${full_composition_pipeline}; then
        options="$options, ForceFullCompositionPipeline=On"
        changed=true
        echo "${display}: Add ForceFullCompositionPipeline=On"
    fi
    new_meta_mode="${new_meta_mode}${display}: ${resolution} {$options}${end}"
done <<< "$meta_mode_converted"

if $changed; then
    nvidia-settings "${extraOpts[@]}" -a CurrentMetaMode="${new_meta_mode}"
fi
```

Hope that helps.

Answer (score 0):

Here is my script with options.
You can choose:

- either you want to set only the  `ForceCompositionPipeline`

  or also the  `ForceFullCompositionPipeline`

  or unset at all
- for the first display only

  or for all connected displays

`~/bin/nvvsync`:

```bash
#!/bin/bash

USAGE() {
    echo "${0##*/}         Set only for the first display."
    echo "${0##*/} -a      Set for all displays (bad idea)."
    echo "${0##*/} -f      Set also the 'ForceFullCompositionPipeline'."
    echo "${0##*/} -u      Unset."
    echo "${0##*/} -v      Verbose."
    echo "${0##*/} -h      Show this help."
    exit 1
}
while getopts "afuvh\?" OPTION; do
  case "$OPTION" in
    a )  all_displays=1                           ;;
    f )  full=1                                   ;;
    u )  unset=1                                  ;;
    v )  verbose=1                                ;;
    h )  USAGE                                    ;;
    \?)  USAGE                                    ;;
    * )  echo "Unknown option \"$OPTION\""; USAGE ;;
  esac
done
shift $(($OPTIND-1))

s="$(nvidia-settings -q CurrentMetaMode -t)"
s="${s#*" :: "}"

# Check if more than one display is active
expr "$s" : ".*DPY-2.*" >/dev/null || single_display=1
# Check if ForceCompositionPipeline is already set
expr "$s" : ".*ForceCompositionPipeline=.*" >/dev/null && Comp_is_set=true || Comp_is_set=false
# Check if ForceFullCompositionPipeline is already set
 expr "$s" : ".*ForceFullCompositionPipeline=.*" >/dev/null && FullComp_is_set=true || FullComp_is_set=false

UNSET() {
    if $Comp_is_set; then
        s="$(echo "$s" | sed -rn "s/(,| )?(,| )?ForceCompositionPipeline=(On|Off)//gp")"
    fi
    if $FullComp_is_set; then
        s="$(echo "$s" | sed -rn "s/(,| )?(,| )?FullCompositionPipeline=(On|Off)//gp")"
    fi
    nvidia-settings -a CurrentMetaMode="${s}"
    exit
}
(($unset)) && UNSET

if [[ "${s}" != "" ]]; then
    (($verbose)) && echo -e "Initial:\n${s}\n"

    # Set only for the first display
    if ! (($all_displays)); then
        # CompositionPipeline
        if $Comp_is_set; then
            s="$(echo "$s" | sed -rn '0,/ForceCompositionPipeline/ s/((,| )?(,| )?)ForceCompositionPipeline=(On|Off)/\1ForceCompositionPipeline=On/p')"
        else
            if (($single_display)); then
                s="${s//\}/, ForceCompositionPipeline=On\}}"
            else
                s="$(echo "$s" | sed -rn 's/(DPY-1:.*)(})(, DPY-2)/\1, ForceCompositionPipeline=On\2\3/p')"
            fi
        fi

        # FullCompositionPipeline
        if (($full)); then
            if $FullComp_is_set; then
                s="$(echo "$s" | sed -rn '0,/ForceFullCompositionPipeline/ s/((,| )?(,| )?)ForceFullCompositionPipeline=(On|Off)/\1ForceCompositionPipeline=On/p')"
            else
                if (($single_display)); then
                    s="${s//\}/, ForceFullCompositionPipeline=On\}}"
                else
                    s="$(echo "$s" | sed -rn 's/(DPY-1:.*)(})(, DPY-2)/\1, ForceFullCompositionPipeline=On\2\3/p')"
                fi
            fi
        fi
        (($verbose)) && echo -e "Result:\n${s}"

    # Set for all displays (bad idea)
    else
        # CompositionPipeline
        if $Comp_is_set; then
            s="$(echo "$s" | sed -rn "s/(,| )?(,| )?ForceCompositionPipeline=(On|Off)//gp")"
        fi
        s="${s//\}/, ForceCompositionPipeline=On\}}"
        
        # FullCompositionPipeline
        if (($full)); then
            if $FullComp_is_set; then
                s="$(echo "$s" | sed -rn "s/(,| )?(,| )?FullCompositionPipeline=(On|Off)//gp")"
            fi
            s="${s//\}/, FullCompositionPipeline=On\}}"
        fi
        (($verbose)) && echo -e "Result:\n${s}"
    fi

    nvidia-settings -a CurrentMetaMode="${s}"
fi
```